# Is binding a click event to a null selector dangerous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-events

Is there anything wrong that can happen if I bind a null selector using `on`? It would simplify my code and allow me to chain a few things if I didn't have to explicitly check if the selector is null myself.

Any performance, security, or memory-leak implications if I do this a dozen times on my page?

```
$(document.body).on('click', null, function () { ... }
```

Comment: Why do you need the delegated event handler? Wouldn't a simple .click work? The body is always on the page...

Comment: Because the element could be dynamically added later.

Comment: What version of JQuery?

Comment: Dozen times would imply dozen events per click on any element.

Comment: @TruMan1 it does not matter if the element is added later, the event will bubble to body and your handler will catch it. I'll add an answer and a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on dynamically adding elements, there is nothing wrong by binding on a higher element using the `.on()` method.

Keep in mind though you have to specify a selector that will ultimately define the dynamically added elements.

The code below will fire when a label is clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', 'label', function(e) {
    alert('dynamically added label clicked');
});
```

This code will fire when any element is clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', null, function (e) {
    alert('fired regardless what element you clicked');
});
```

From the jQuery docs:

> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements
>   that will call the handler. **If the selector is null or omitted, the
>   handler is always called when it reaches the selected element.**

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that the elements that raise the click event are dynamically added you can still use a direct event handler on body and catch those events.

The delegated event handler gives you the opportunity to filter out some of those click events, but it seems that's not the case since you are setting the selector to null.

For example, if you have a div and add buttons inside and add an event handler to the click event on the div you'll catch all the click events from all the buttons, even the ones added dynamically.

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="add button" id="buttonAddMore"/>
    <span id="whatClicked"></span>
</div>

$('div').on("click", function(event){
    $('#whatClicked').text("the id of the clicked element inside the div is: " + event.target.id);
});
```

[**This fiddle demonstrates this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/X4B4H/).

The delegated events have other subtleties, such as, they won't respond to events raised in the elements they are registered in, in this example that would be a click on the div, and that might be important.

Either way if you look at how the events are registered, in your case you can have a look by calling in the console $._data(document.body, "events") and have a look at the click event handler with your method and registered using the shorthand version (i.e. `.click` or `on("click", function() {...})`) you'll see that they produce the same object, except for the selector being null (.on("click", null...) in one case and undefined in the other (.click)